# Force of a Train

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Imagine that there are two trains and  the first train is twice as long as the second train. They have the same mass per unit length and they are traveling at exactly the same speed.

If the first train hit me, would it hit me with twice as much force as the second train?  These are two distinct situations: 1) I am hit by the first train only, 2) I am hit by the second train only.

Force is mass times acceleration, so if the one train has twice the mass, then it seems likely that it would have twice the force.  But I am not sure.

Comment: when the second train is so long , the collision wont be experienced by other coaches, would they ?  if you consider just two engines of m and 2m masses then the force it exerts can be easier to visualize i feel . also are you stopping the train or is this a case of hit and go ? if its the latter then both forces you feel will be the same i think as the whole train isn't actually feeling the collision of the engine and a human body .

Comment: @Gowtham, I should probably have used buses as my example instead of trains.  In the context of trains, I would only be considering an engine.  One engine would be half as long as the other one.  They would both have the same mass per unit length.  So the one train would have half the mass as the other train.

Comment: then i think the answers have addressed your question . i am still doubtful how a long train actually transmits force(or impulse) to a human relative to its length .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in force to stop the trains you are talking about here is *the difference in force is needed to bring the train to a stop within a particular distance* Let me tell you what I mean.

When you try to stop the train, you'll obviously be dragged in front of the train. Say the dragging causes an uniform force (due to the friction from the ground) $f_1$ to act on the heavier train, and $f_2$ to act on the other. $f_1$ and $f_2$ act such that both trains come to rest within the same distance $x$. You say that both trains travel with the same velocity $v$, but have different masses. So, let the heavier train have mass $M$ and the lighter one have mass $m$.

The trains thus have kinetic energies $\frac 12 M v^2$ and $\frac 12 m v^2$.

In stopping the trains, the work you'll have to do to is $W_1=f_1x=\frac 12 Mv^2$ for the heavier train and $W_2=f_2x=\frac 12 mv^2$ for the other one. Once we divide the two, $${f_1x \over f_2x}={\frac 12 Mv^2 \over \frac 12 mv^2}\implies \frac {f_1}{f_2}=\frac {M}{m}$$

Thus, $$f_1 > f_2$$

By Newton's third law, the force you exert on the train is equal what the train exerts on you. Thus $$\boxed {force \ exerted \ by \ the \ heavier \ train \ on \ you \ > \ force \ exerted \ by \ the \ lighter \ train \ on \ you}$$

Comment: Hi ! i agree with you when question is about stopping the train . What do you think will happen when its just a hit and go rather than train being stopped ? the impulse(or force) will be same i feel if we are considering a human in the way of the trains .

Comment: @Gowtham For a given reaction time $\tau$ common to both cases during which the impulse is delivered to the human, you can see that the lighter object delivers lesser impulse to the human than the heavier one, and thus (lesser impulse)/$\tau$=(lesser force)

Comment: i agree to that statement, but is the whole object delivering(long train and the entire mass of this) the impulse to the very small object(human) , just imagine only the engine and no coaches(at same speed) hitting the human, will the force(or impulse) be different

Comment: @Gowtham Practically speaking, the scale of the force acting is so high that whether the object is just an engine or the whole train, by the time the impulse is completely delivered, the human body itself becomes *undefined*. But hypothetically speaking, if we define the human body and the train as though they are two solid spheres with a defined coefficient of restitution, we can say that the force exerted by the engine alone will be lesser than that of the whole train. Even then, however, the masses involved are so large that in both cases, the human will charge...

Comment: ..ahead with approximately the same velocity $2v$, just a bit lesser in the engine case.

Comment: yes i am convinced when we consider them as spheres. but its just confusing if the length of the train (meaning more mass) actually means more force . i just feel the whole train wont even feel the impulse it imparted to the human . only the coaches in front would feel and eventually the length of the train woudlnt matter when the speed is the same.

Comment: @Gowtham You are right. The bogies which make up the train don't normally touch each other (when in constant velocity) but are connected by a connector such that the bogies are loosely held in place. Since they are loosely held, it means that the train is not a continuous body but a collection of seperate bodies (bogies) moving with the same velocity one behind the other. When the bogies do not touch each other, they are seperate masses. But when they do, they become one body and the mass of that body is greater than the induvidual bogies. ...

Comment: ...If it brakes to a stop, for example, then all bogies must collide (i.e touch) with the next one since every bogey starts decellerating earlier than the one behind it. Thus, the mass of the "train" keeps increasing as it decellerates. However, if it does not brake to a stop, and instead decreses its velocity only a little bit as in when it hits a human, by the time the engine hits the next bogey, the impulse is already delivered to the human and he is speeding away. ..

Comment: ...Thus, the number of bogies does not matter now, since the effective mass of the train that collides with the human is only that of the engine, as it does not touch the next bogey.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should note that Newton's law says when $F$ acts on a mass $m$, then *that mass* will move with acceleration $a$.

Here, we should apply the laws of collision and by using the conservation of momentum, find out what your velocity will be after the collision. Before collision we have: $p_{tot}=mv$ and after collision $p_{tot}'=mv'+MV$ where $M$ and $V$ are your mass and speed, $m$ and $v$ are mass and speed of train(s). Also for energy, we have $$mv^2=mv'^2+MV^2$$Now by putting $p_{tot}=p_{tot}'$ and solving the equations, we find $$V=\frac{2mv}{M+m}.$$
Now you can see the bigger train will give you more speed (or more momentum) and so the collision is harder, which means the change of your momentum is more. (recall $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$). On the other hand, since $M \ll m$, so this exceeding is not obvious and maybe we can say the effect of both trains are similar.